# Reading a line from index in Text file in VB

Tags: vb.net, readline

I'm creating a Quiz Application in which I have added all the questions and options in a single text file.But I have no idea how to move to next question when I click next button and previous question when I click previous button.The problem I'm currently facing is reading a specific line from the text file.

**This is the function for Next Button**

```
 Public Function Next_Ques() As Integer
        Label1.Text = file.ReadLine()
        RadioButton1.Text = file.ReadLine()
        RadioButton2.Text = file.ReadLine()
        RadioButton3.Text = file.ReadLine()
        RadioButton4.Text = file.ReadLine()
        ansKey = file.ReadLine()
        Return 0
    End Function
```

The Next Button is working perfectly.But i don't know how to read the Previous lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to load all questions into a list. Here's how to do it.

## 1. Create a class to hold a question.

This class is needed so you can store the question in memory. You can use List(Of Question) to store a list of questions.

```
Public Class Question

    Public Property Question As String
    Public Property Choice1 As String
    Public Property Choice2 As String
    Public Property Choice3 As String
    Public Property Choice4 As String
    Public Property Answer As String

End Class
```

## 2. Load all questions from the text file into a list.

Declare this 2 variables in the form level.

```
Private currentQuestion As Integer
Private listOfQuestions As List(Of Question) = New List(Of Question)
```

Then write some code in the form's load event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' open a text file
    Using reader = New StreamReader("Quiz.txt")

        ' read a line
        Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
        'loop as long as it's not empty
        While (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))

            ' create a question instance and put the data into it
            Dim question = New Question
            question.Question = line
            question.Choice1 = reader.ReadLine()
            question.Choice2 = reader.ReadLine()
            question.Choice3 = reader.ReadLine()
            question.Choice4 = reader.ReadLine()
            question.Answer = reader.ReadLine()

            ' add the question into the list
            listOfQuestions.Add(question)

            ' read next question
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        End While

    End Using

    ' load first question
    If listOfQuestions.Count > 0 Then
        LoadQuestion(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

## 3. Add a method in the form to load the question into the form.

I rename the controls' names so it reflects their usage.

```
Sub LoadQuestion(questionIndex As Integer)

    Dim question = listOfQuestions(questionIndex)
    currentQuestion = questionIndex

    With question
        lblQuestion.Text = .Question
        radChoice1.Text = .Choice1
        radChoice2.Text = .Choice2
        radChoice3.Text = .Choice3
        radChoice4.Text = .Choice4
    End With

End Sub
```

## 4. Create event handlers for Previous and Next buttons.

```
Private Sub btnPreviousQuestion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPreviousQuestion.Click

    If (currentQuestion > 0) Then
        LoadQuestion(currentQuestion - 1)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnNextQuestion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextQuestion.Click

    If (currentQuestion < listOfQuestions.Count - 1) Then
        LoadQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope it's clear enough since I added some comments in my code.

## Full form's code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private currentQuestion As Integer
    Private listOfQuestions As List(Of Question) = New List(Of Question)


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' open a text file
        Using reader = New StreamReader("Quiz.txt")

            ' read a line
            Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
            'loop as long as it's not empty
            While (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))

                ' create a question instance and put the data into it
                Dim question = New Question
                question.Question = line
                question.Choice1 = reader.ReadLine()
                question.Choice2 = reader.ReadLine()
                question.Choice3 = reader.ReadLine()
                question.Choice4 = reader.ReadLine()
                question.Answer = reader.ReadLine()

                ' add the question into the list
                listOfQuestions.Add(question)

                ' read next question
                line = reader.ReadLine()
            End While

        End Using

        ' load first question
        If listOfQuestions.Count > 0 Then
            LoadQuestion(0)
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub LoadQuestion(questionIndex As Integer)

        Dim question = listOfQuestions(questionIndex)
        currentQuestion = questionIndex

        With question
            lblQuestion.Text = .Question
            radChoice1.Text = .Choice1
            radChoice2.Text = .Choice2
            radChoice3.Text = .Choice3
            radChoice4.Text = .Choice4
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPreviousQuestion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPreviousQuestion.Click

        If (currentQuestion > 0) Then
            LoadQuestion(currentQuestion - 1)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNextQuestion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextQuestion.Click

        If (currentQuestion < listOfQuestions.Count - 1) Then
            LoadQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you need to access current question's answer, you can take it directly from the list. Use listOfQuestions(currentQuestion).Answer to get the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reading all of them into string buffer and manipulating would be much easier than searching in file stream. Use following command:

```
Dim datas String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
' for example:
Dim firstQuestion as String = datas(0)
Dim firstQuestionOption1 as String = datas(1)
Dim secondQuestion as String = datas(6) ' accord to your data structure
Dim secondQuestionOpetion2 as String = data(7)
```

then you can traverse it freely - fetch out the quiz question and options , of course , according to your data arrangement.

after that , use a index to memorize which question is on working , when user press next/previous button , calculate the right start index , and fetch the strings from the **datas** we just read before.

And show them on your UI components , i believe all works done here:)